# Invalid date error when parsing

Tags: ruby

I want to create an array of dates using the code below

```
arr = []
for i in (1..31) do
  arr << Date.new(2014, 9, i)
end
```

I get an "Invalid date" error. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: September has 30 days, not 31.

Comment: @mode_x: change this line `for i in (1..31) do` to `for i in (1...31) do`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to resolve this?

You could replace `31` with `30`, but there's another way to reference the last day. Many `Date` methods accept negative arguments to count backwards:

```
first_day = Date.new(2014, 9, 1) #=> #<Date: 2014-09-01 ((2456902j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
last_day = Date.new(2014, 9, -1) #=> #<Date: 2014-09-30 ((2456931j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

You can use this to create a `Range`:

```
september_range = first_day..last_day
```

Or an `Array`:

```
september_days = (first_day..last_day).to_a
```

Comment: never knew about negative in `Date.new()` class. +1 for reference the last day.

Comment: Note also that `Date.new(2014, 9, -1)==Date.new(2014, 10, 1)-1 => true`.

Answer (score 1):

you could write:

```
arr = (Date.new(2014,9,1)..Date.new(2014,9,30)).to_a
```

or without days:

```
arr = (Date.new(2014,9)...Date.new(2014,10)).to_a
```